# My view is not properly displaying data from the controller store as a javascript object

Tags: javascript, pug, mean-stack

I have this controller trying to pass `pageHeader.title` and `pageHeader.strapline` to a jade template view.

Here is the controller.

```
module.exports.homelist = function(req, res) {
    res.render('locations-list', {
     title: 'Loc8r - find a place to work with wifi',
     pageHeader: {
        title: 'Loc8r',
        strapline: 'Find places to work with wifi near you!'
     } 
    });
};
```

Here is the part of the template that I need to update. (The jade template has given me problems through this whole app. Every little wrong space seems to completely mess it up)

```
block content
 #banner.page-header
  .row
   .col-lg-6
   h1= pageHeader.title
    small &nbsp; #{pageHeader.strapline}
```

The `pageHeader` objects will not display properly.

Comment: what is the error that you getting?

Comment: error message your receiving?

Comment: TypeError: C:\Users\Michael\Loc8r\app_server\views\locations-  list.jade:7  
    5|   .row  
    6|    .col-lg-6  
  > 7|    h1= pageHeader.title  
    8|     small &nbsp; #{pageHeader.strapline}  
    9|  .row  
    10|   .col-xs-12.col-sm-8  
  
Cannot read property 'title' of undefined

Comment: Sorry I don't know that formatting on here very well yet.

Answer (score 0):

In jade there are two possibilities that you getting an error,

Indentation and use of space and tab on same page
Maybe,

```
block content
  #banner.page-header
    .row
      .col-lg-6
        h1= pageHeader.title
          small &nbsp; #{pageHeader.strapline}
```

Or need to use

```
  h1= locals.pageHeader.title
```

Comment: I checked the indentation and it all displays fine if I hard code a value in the pageHeader.title place. And the locals.pageHeader.title doesn't seem to be working either.

Comment: Putting only title seems to make the page display. But it doesn't display the information stored in the title property. It displays the word Home.

Comment: Now I am getting Cannot read property 'title' of undefined, with pageHeader.title Is there something wrong with part of the code in my controller that I am missing?

Comment: Let me simulate this on my system, will get back to you....ehich express version you using?

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea what was wrong, but I deleted the comma after title: 'Loc8r...' line in the controller which broke the app. Then added it back and saved and voila works perfectly now. Jade gives me too many problems!